# mapView is not Zooming to Coordinates

Tags: xcode, ios5, mapkit

I've looked through existing questions and believe I'm following the rules, but some reason my map is not zooming.  I have put in a breakpoint to make sure my coordinates are making it through and everything seems to be OK there.

Below is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 260, 169)];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

   Bar *maps = self.detailItem;
   MKCoordinateSpan span;
   span.latitudeDelta = .02;
   span.longitudeDelta = .02;

   CLLocationDegrees latDegree = [maps.barLat doubleValue];
   CLLocationDegrees longDegree = [maps.barLong doubleValue];
   CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latDegree, longDegree);

   MKCoordinateRegion region;
   region.center = location;
   region.span = span;
   [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do in the `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:` callback ... that gets called when the region is going to change (e.g. on user pan or zoom), and you are responding by commanding another region change.  Maybe that's just for debugging?

I think your question is about why your map won't zoom, right?

If you want to be sure your map supports zoom, add this code:

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 260, 169)];
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
mapView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

however, I'm wondering if what you're seeing is just that your map is pretty small.  It's less than half the screen size.  On the simulator, I found it difficult to perform the pinch gesture (which causes the zoom), and even on my real device, it wasn't easy to get my two fingers into that small view area.  But, on both platforms, I definitely did see that code allowing zoom (iOS 5.0).

Can you increase the `frame` size of your map, and make sure it wasn't just that it's hard to pinch within a small area?